# MySQL inserting id dependent fields from two different tables into a third table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, each with an int id for each row

Table 1 contains 3 columns and the records were inserted from another table so their ids are not sequential.
teammate_id
first_name
last_name

Table 2 contains 2 columns, the id and the second column which include lots of hobbies
hobby_id
hobby

Table 3 is empty. I want to insert the students' first and last names from table 1 in two columns and their specific hobby (I have their hobby information from an external source and the hobby is listed in Table 2) in column 3. I tried inserting the values of the corresponding id numbers but rather than the values, the id numbers is what got inserted into the third table, so I now have a table with the correct id ints but not the corresponding fields for those ints.

I tried using LEFT JOIN but can't seem to make it work and I found it confusing. Is there a command that can take advantage of the ids and pull in the values of first_name, last_name_ from the first table and hobby from the second table into the third table? Or what would be a best practice better way to approach the problem?

Comment: For a start, some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: I am pretty new to Stack Overflow as well, ngolden. Welcome! Check out my answer below, which has some details you may want to use when posting your question as well.

Comment: Hi Honeyboy Wilson and thanks. Table 1 14 Joe Smith, 17 Mary Jones Table 2 1 ice skating, 2 soccer, 3 football, 4 knitting Table 3 should have records Joe Smith football, Mary Jones knitting and so on...so id 14 Table 1 teammates has JoeSmith record 14 and matched with record 3 football from Table 2 hobbys to be displayed in Table 3. Teammates may be a confusing designation - it is for a group of people on a work team and isn't related to the hobbies.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and your answer, Lars! I'm checking it out now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow your description as best I could and created [a Fiddle, which might be of help.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ef24/1)

From your description, there is seems to be a relation missing between hobbies and teammates, so I created one more table for that purpose: `teammate_hobby`.

For the remaining tables I used the names given in your description.

```
create table table1 (teammate_id integer, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100));
create table table2 (hobby_id integer, hobby varchar(100));

create table table3 (first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100), hobby varchar(100));

insert into table1 values (1, 'Charles', 'Aznavour');
insert into table1 values (7, 'Amy', 'Winehouse');

insert into table2 values (1, 'Singing');
insert into table2 values (3, 'Running');


create table teammate_hobby (teammate_id integer, hobby_id integer);

insert into teammate_hobby values (1, 1);
insert into teammate_hobby values (1, 3);

insert into table3
select first_name, last_name, hobby
from table1 tb1
 inner join teammate_hobby tmt
  on tb1.teammate_id = tmt.teammate_id
 inner join table2 tb2
  on tb2.hobby_id = tmt.hobby_id;
```

Table3 now has the following values:

```
first_name  last_name   hobby
Charles Aznavour    Singing
Charles Aznavour    Running
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am studying the code and I can see you made an additional table which is what I am missing - thank you for showing me that. Now we can use  INNER JOIN instead of the LEFT JOIN I was trying to do. I see where you insert the values so that it will be Charles Singing (1, 1) and Charles running (1, 3). I am uncertain about your final block of code - I see you using the INNER JOIN. When you wrote from table1 tb1 and teamate_hobby tmt and table2 tb2 - I see you are referencing each table but where did the tb1, tb2, and tmt come from and what are they doing? Thanks!

Comment: Inner joins make sense here, because you do not need rows in Table3 where the hobby is missing. As for tb2 and tb1, they are simply aliases. The table teammate_hobby is what's called a many-to-many resolver, and is required because many people can have many hobbies.

Comment: Also was not aware of SQL Fiddle - very cool! Thanks!

Comment: If you find the information helpful, I would appreciate upvotes. I am relatively new to StackOverflow as well, and every point counts. If my answer works for you, please also accept.

Comment: So when you use tb1 it automatically creates it as an alias? No other config necessary? I'm  learning about many to many, one to many etc. - thank for pointing that out :)

Comment: Yes. You will find a lot of people use a, b, c as aliases for their tables. I tend to use three letters, which I find short yet descriptive. Thanks for the acceptance of my answer. Would you mind clicking to upvote as well?

Comment: It would be best if you did not answer a Question until it meets the quality standards of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did the upvote Lars and it said it was recorded but because I don't have enough reputation points it won't be visible - sorry!

Comment: Scratte, I am just a poor tired student doing my best to learn honestly and sometimes we just need a little guidance. I am sorry my question isn't up to your standards but rest assured Lars's kindness has helped me tremendously and fueled my desire to learn. We are not all professionals on here but nor are we trying for an easy answer - I worked on this question 3 hours last night until 3:30am.

Comment: I followed SO's guidelines as I wrote my question. My actually MySQL is on a different barebones computer because it wouldn't install on this one, so copying code snippets for me is problematic and thus not in my description. "If you don't know, it's simply awful, if you do know, its awfully simple."

Comment: I read this somewhere... Be kind to others.
Including those that don't "deserve" it.
They may need it most

Comment: Lars - I just got my code to run successfully. I both understand why and am able to implement the concept you showed me in the future. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help.